# Is it correct to say "understood question" as well as "understandable question"?

Tags: usage

Is it correct to say "**understood question**" as well as "**understandable** question"?

Someone wrote me it and I'm not sure if it is mistake or another variant.

The context is: " It is an understood sentence."

Comment: Was it in note-form, as in "*(I) **understood** (the) **question**, (and I ) **sent** (an) **answer***"?

Comment: I just added now the context to the post: "It is an understood sentence"

Comment: Hm, "It is a **well-**understood question/sentence" would be fine. With just *understood* on its own, it's a little awkward.

Comment: I've heard this structure but not in a context like this. "E.G. How, at the molecular level, the myriad cell types in an organism manage to stably preserve their distinct identities is an important but poorly **understood question** in biology.SOURCE: Human Molecular Genetics" And as you see, it's very commonly used after the adverb "**poorly**" E.G **Poorly understood questions**, underutilized rating scale categories can seriously impair the accuracy and reliability of PRO measurements"or "One **poorly understood question** is the role of BACE1 in the brain, target organ of BACE1 inhibitors"

Answer (score 1):

> It is an understood sentence.

is certainly not idiomatic. without additional context I am not clear what the intended meaning is, but whatever it is there is almost surely a better way to say it.

As LawrenceC's answer explains, "understood" can mean "implied, but not stated" but "It is an understood sentence." would not be a natural way to describe a sentence that was implied but not explicitly said.

If the meaning is that someone was able to understand the sentence, that could be phrased as:

> It was an understandable sentence

or perhaps

> It was clear that the sentence could be understood.

"Understood can also mean "known, with reasons and explanations that are also known" as mentioned in the comment by  AmirhoseinRiazi

> The interaction of smell with memory is poorly understood
>
> The effect of friction on motion is well-understood.
>
> The circulation of the blood was not understood by the ancient Greeks.

This use does not seem to be what the question intends.

Answer (score 0):

*Understood* means not only "was able to receive the meaning" but can also mean "not expressed, assumed."

> It's been understood we don't talk to Mike (we didn't talk about not talking to Mike, we just assumed we should not and did not).

This is different from *understandable* which means "able to be interpreted or get the meaning."

> I understood you didn't want me to talk to Mike (I told you this and you are acknowledging you know what I mean).

If you want to say "able to be interpreted or get the meaning" the word *understandable* is better.

Comment: So to say "It is an understood sentence", considered correct?